# How to give an echo a "div class"?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, echo

trying to add a css class to my echo to style this, i've tried a few variations but it didn't work.

this is the current line of code that i'm using:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 32 ); ?>
```

Comment: The documentation for [get_avatar](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) has an argument of options that allows you to set a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final param of get_avatar is an array containing various options, including the ability to append a class.

`echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 32, '', '', array("class"=>"your class"));`

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/ for full details.

If on the other hand you just want to wrap the existing output in a div, then you just need to wrap it in the div tag ie. `echo "<div class='bla'>".get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 32)."</div>";`